# How to getContentHeight when using loadData?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I need to get the height of my webview, which I load with static content, but the height returned is always zero.

I initially thought it was because the webview hadn't loaded when requesting the height, so I tried setting it in OnPageFinished through a webview client. This works when loading a page from the internet, but not when loading local content.

```
    String html = "<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><p>Insert content here</p></body></html>";
            qWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
    qWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null); 

    qWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            int height = qWebView.getContentHeight();
            Toast.makeText(WebviewHeightTestActivity.this, String.valueOf(height), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
  <WebView android:id="@+id/webView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></WebView>
```